# memory game in jQuery save image in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am creating memory game using jQuery, my problem is one specific thing, that i dont find where i am wrong.

**The way i built it:**
All images have default src value, after one click the src change, if the the two image that clicked are not the same, the default src value return.

**The problem is:**
after the defualt src value return, when i click on the image again, the last shown src should retrive from the array, but its show antoher random image instead.

**This is the relevent code**

```
var imgArr1 = ["images/skinny-unicorn.png", "images/all-757448_640.jpg", "images/alm-770667_640.jpg", "images/audi-798530_640.jpg", "images/landscape-691462_640.jpg", "images/skinny-unicorn.png", "images/all-757448_640.jpg", "images/alm-770667_640.jpg", "images/audi-798530_640.jpg", "images/landscape-691462_640.jpg"];

var arrStr = [32];

$('.img').click(function(){
    //var openCount = openCardCount();

    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    if(getFromArray(id) != 'null')
    {
        var oldSrc = getFromArray(id);
        $('#' + id).attr('src',oldSrc);

    }
    else
    {
        var src = $(this).attr("src");
        if(src == "images/back.png")
        {

            $('#' + id).attr('src',ChangeFirstArray());
        }
        var openCard = openCardCount();
        if(openCard == 1)
        {
            storeInArray(id,src);
            $(".img").attr("src","images/back.png");
        }
    }
});



/* create an array of id and src that as been allready clicked once */
function storeInArray(id,src)
{

    for(var i = 0 ; i < arrStr.length; i++)
    {
        if(arrStr[i] == "")
        {
            arrStr[i] = id;
            arrStr[i+1] = src;
        }
    }


}


/* check if there is old image on this id, return the src if there is one, if not return null */ 
function getFromArray(id)
{
    for(var i = 0 ; i < arrStr.length; i++)
    {
        if( id == arrStr[i])
            var src = arrStr[i+1];
        var src = 'null';
    }

    return src;
}
```

update for the getFromArray function, the problem still exist

```
function getFromArray(id)
{
    for(var i = 0 ; i < arrStr.length; i++)
    {
        if( id == arrStr[i])
            {
              var src = arrStr[i+1];
            }
         else{var src = 'null';}         
    }

    return src;
}
```

Comment: in `getFromArray` why are you redeclaring `src`as `'null'` after setting it to `arrStr[i+1]` ?

Comment: the null is the else statement, if the id not equal to arrStr[i], the src get null

Comment: yes but if it _is_ equal, then after being set to `arrStr[i+1]` it will be set to `'null'` again. therefore `getFromArray` would always return `'null'`

Comment: I did the change you told me, the problem is still exist.

Answer (score 0):

After the line where you set

```
src = arrStr[i+1];
```

you can add the line

```
return src;
```

as you do not need to keep going through the rest of the for loop

```
function getFromArray(id)
{
    for(var i = 0 ; i < arrStr.length; i++)
    {
        if( id == arrStr[i])
            {
              var src = arrStr[i+1];
              return src; // this is inserted so that the loop ends after you find the value you are after.
            }
         else{var src = 'null';}         
    }

    return src; // this will only occur if you get to the end of the loop and the value was not found
                // always returns null
}
```

To simplify the function:

```
function getFromArray(id)
{
    for(var i = 0 ; i < arrStr.length; i++)
    {
        if( id == arrStr[i])
            {
              var src = arrStr[i+1];
              return src; 
            }      
    }
    return 'null'; 
}
```